# TimeSpan difference between elements in List

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List` with following objects:

```
public class DomainTimeErrors
{
    public int DomainId { get; set; }
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FinishedAt { get; set; }
    public string Domain { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

How to get those objects with the same value in `Url` property where `TimeSpan` between values in `FinishedAt` is more then 1 hour.

EDITED:

From the following list:

```
var list = new List<DomainTimeErrors>
{
new DomainTimeErrors { DomainId = 1, JobId = 1, FinishedAt = "2017-12-01 12:00", Domain = "so.com", Url = "so.com/id=1" },
new DomainTimeErrors { DomainId = 1, JobId = 2, FinishedAt = "2017-12-01 12:55", Domain = "so.com", Url = "so.com/id=1" },
new DomainTimeErrors { DomainId = 1, JobId = 3, FinishedAt = "2017-12-01 13:55", Domain = "so.com", Url = "so.com/id=1" },
new DomainTimeErrors { DomainId = 1, JobId = 4, FinishedAt = "2017-12-01 14:00", Domain = "so.com", Url = "so.com/id=1" },
new DomainTimeErrors { DomainId = 1, JobId = 11, FinishedAt = "2017-12-01 12:00", Domain = "so.com", Url = "so.com/id=2" },
new DomainTimeErrors { DomainId = 1, JobId = 12, FinishedAt = "2017-12-01 12:05", Domain = "so.com", Url = "so.com/id=2" },
new DomainTimeErrors { DomainId = 1, JobId = 13, FinishedAt = "2017-12-01 12:55", Domain = "so.com", Url = "so.com/id=2" },
new DomainTimeErrors { DomainId = 1, JobId = 14, FinishedAt = "2017-12-01 12:56", Domain = "so.com", Url = "so.com/id=2" }
}
```

I would like to get only one of those where `Url = "so.com/id=1"` because the time difference between the earliest and the latest is more then 1 hour

Comment: what have you tried? see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What if there are multiple sets of URLs that are shared between multiple objects?  E.g. what if three objects have a URL "https:\\abc.com" and four have a URL "https:\\def.com"?  Which one wins?

Comment: If there are 5 objects with same url and three of them have FinishedAt difference greater than 1h, you want these three or you want all the concrete combinations where the difference is greater than 1h?

Comment: @TimSchmelter if more then 2 have the same Url I want only one of them, value of `FinishedAt` is not important, I just would like to get the Domain and Url @MikeT to be honest I don't know how to start

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk: now i have no idea anymore what you really want.  In your question you say that you want _"those objects with the same value in Url property where TimeSpan between values in FinishedAt is more then 1 hour"_. Now you say that you want only one and FinishedAt is not important.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have edited my question and gave an example.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk ok have a look below and you should have a starting point now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a Linq query i would expect it to look something like

```
from a in List
join b in List
  on a.Url equals b.Url
where (b.FinishedAt - a.FinishedAt).TotalHours>=1
select b;
```

you would then use grouping and selectors to screen out unwanted values

ie

```
from a in List.Where(i=>i.FinishedAt.HasValue)
join b in List.Where(i=>i.FinishedAt.HasValue)
  on a.Url equals b.Url
where (b.FinishedAt - a.FinishedAt).TotalHours>=1
group b by b.url into g
select g.FirstOrDefault();
```

EDIT
Given your edit i would now expect it to look more like this

```
from i in List
where i.FinishedAt != null
order by i.FinsihedAt 
group i by i.Url into g
where (g.Last().FinsihedAt -g.First().FinsihedAt ).TotalHours >=1
select g.Last();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Linq to Object, I think this linq's query answer your question:

```
Func<IEnumerable<DomainTimeErrors>, bool> checkdiffrent = (items) =>
{
    var itemsCount=items.Count();
    if (itemsCount == 0 || itemsCount == 1)
      return true;

    var sortedItems=items.OrderBy(a=> a.FinishedAt.Value);
    var firstItem=sortedItems.First();
    var lastItem= sortedItems.Last();
    return (firstItem.FinishedAt- lastItem.FinishedAt).Value.TotalHours > 1;
}

var itemWithFinishDate = DomainTimeErrorsCollection.Where(a=> a.FinishedAt.HasValue).
var result = itemWithFinishDate.GroupBy(i=> i.Url).
                Where(sameUrls => checkdiffrent(sameUrls))
                .SelectMany(a=> a);
```

Comment: if you sort the items then group them the group should maintain the sort, this will reduce the number of times you are sorting the data, also the group by and select many cancel each other out i think all you need is a  `Select(a=>a.Last())`

Comment: @MikeT  .Net framework use quick sort and it seem there is no differentiation that all items be sorted once or all partition be sorted separately.